# count number rows with groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I had the following function in pandas 0.17:

```
df['numberrows'] = df.groupby(['column1','column2','column3'], as_index=False)[['column1']].transform('count').astype('int')
```

But I upgraded pandas today and now I get the error:

> ```
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
> ```
>
> line 3810, in insert
>       raise ValueError('cannot insert {}, already exists'.format(item))
>
> ValueError: cannot insert column1, already exists

What has changed in the update which causes this function to not work anymore?

I want to groupby the columns and add a column which has the amount or rows of the groupby.

If what I did before was not a good function, another way of grouping while getting the amount of rows that were grouped is also welcome.

EDIT:

small dataset:

```
    column1  column2    column3   
 0  test     car1       1           
 1  test2    car5       2         
 2  test     car1       1         
 3  test4    car2       1      
 4  test2    car1       1
```

outcome would be:

```
    column1  column2    column3   numberrows
 0  test     car1       1           2
 1  test2    car5       2           1     
 3  test4    car2       1           1
 4  test2    car1       1           1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
In [18]: df['new'] = df.groupby(['column1','column2','column3'])['column1'] \
                       .transform('count')

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
  column1 column2  column3  new
0    test    car1        1    2
1   test2    car5        2    1
2    test    car1        1    2
3   test4    car2        1    1
4   test2    car1        1    1
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [26]: df.groupby(['column1','column2','column3'])['column1'] \
           .count().reset_index(name='numberrows')
Out[26]:
  column1 column2  column3  numberrows
0    test    car1        1           2
1   test2    car1        1           1
2   test2    car5        2           1
3   test4    car2        1           1
```

Comment: this gives: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: @user3605780, can you provide a small reproducible data set and desired data set?

Comment: I added a set, your example is almost there, but I need to remove the duplicate rows

Comment: @user3605780 you can use the drop_duplicates() method on the resulting dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is sloppy, you are using `as_index=False` with `transform`.
`as_index=False` will end up pushing those columns back into the dataframe proper when it finds that `column1` already exists... uh-oh.  However, that is completely unnecessary as `transform` handles the index for you.

```
df.groupby(
    ['column1','column2','column3']
)['column1'].transform('count').astype('int')

0    2
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    1
Name: column1, dtype: int64
```

Or make a new column

```
df.assign(
    new=df.groupby(
        ['column1','column2','column3']
    )['column1'].transform('count').astype('int')
)

  column1 column2  column3  new
0    test    car1        1    2
1   test2    car5        2    1
2    test    car1        1    2
3   test4    car2        1    1
4   test2    car1        1    1
```